# How to test each successive element in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a turn system within my code and am wondering whether it is possible to test an individual element in a list to see if it is contained within another list, then go on to another element in the list to see which list that is in. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: sample input and expected output.

Comment: You can use the `in` operator. But if the lists are large, and you need to do lots of tests, it's probably a good idea to build sets from those lists because testing membership of a set is _much_ more efficient than testing membership of a list.

Answer (score 0):

`in` tests for membership.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [4, 5]

[x in b for x in a]
# [False, False, False, True, True]

# the list comprehension above is the same as:
#     acc = []
#     for x in a:
#         acc.append(x in b)
# with the result equal to acc
```

lists can check membership in O(n), while sets take O(1), so if either `a` or `b` is very long, it can be useful to convert `b` to a set first.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [4, 5]
set_b = set(b)

[x in set_b for x in a]
# [False, False, False, True, True]  <-- same as above
```

each check there is done in constant time rather than O(n) where n is bounded by the length of `b`.